# TrueCrypt alternative (encrypt partition)

Tags: encryption

I need to encrypt a partition, truecrypt could use keyfiles, (images and other)
Is there any other encryption tool with GUI which can encrypt entire partitions and not only files/folders?

Answer (score 1):

Truecrypt's advice on this makes sense: use the native FDE that came with your operating system, i.e.

- Bitlocker on Windows
- FileVault on OSX
- whatever your distro suggests (typically Encrypted LVM) on Linux.

(This will not necessarily be a good fit for everyone, but without more details of an individual requirement, it's the best advice you can reasonably  give.)

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention I use LMDE (Linux Mint Debian)

Comment: A quick google suggests that dmcrypt is included in Debian Testing, and hence in LMDE as well.

Comment: yes, I found this, but there is no GUI so it is hard to use for my sister.